# React-native : cannot receive message through FCM in IOS device

Tags: react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have an issue with push notification in iOS devices using Firebase Cloud Messaging although it worked before. When I check apple dev account,I realized that some information has expired (like keys, profiles), I updated all of its and GoogleService-Info.plist but it still not work. Has anyone face with this issue? Please give me a solution. Thanks
[link issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83xCU.png)

Comment: Have you tried [sending a test message via APNS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools)? Just to make sure that everything is working on APNs side.

Comment: Thanks for advising. I have fixed this issue last week. It turns out my project config to wrong firebase project console

Answer (score 0):

Follow all the setup related to

1. Firebase App Integration from [here](https://rnfirebase.io/)
2. Firebase Cloud Messaging from [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage)

For iOS, you need to set up Capabilities(Push Notifications & Background Modes)

You have setup all the things related iOS from [here](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup)

Let me know still you have any queries. I hope it will help you!

Comment: When I inspect firebase console last week, I noticed that APNs Auth key has expired, so I updated it (include keys and profiles apple account), and I also download new GoogleService-Info.plist file and add it to Xcode.xcworkspace, I even test push noti through firebase test push api, it response success but I cannot receive any message. What did I miss? Btw: Should I upload APNs Certificates file to firebase console?

Comment: Yes you have to upload it then after you can receive a notification in iOS Device

Comment: You have to follow Linking APNs with FCM (iOS) section from above link